# Prove $\Bbb R P ^n = e^0 \cup e^1 \cup \dots \cup e^n$, where $e^i$ are $i$-cells, by induction

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, induction

I'm self learning Algebraic topology from Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic topology, and I've come across some difficulty showing the second part of this problem:

> Prove that for each $n \gt 1, \Bbb R P^n$ is obtained from $\Bbb R P^{n-1}$ by attaching an $n$-cell.
>
> Prove $\Bbb R P ^n = e^0 \cup e^1 \cup \dots \cup e^n$, where $e^i$ are $i$-cells, by induction.

In the proof of the first part, $e^n=\{[x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}] \in \Bbb R P^n : x_{n+1} \neq 0\}$.

In an attempt to prove the second part, I assume by the induction hypotheses that $\Bbb R P ^n = e^0 \cup e^1 \cup \dots \cup e^n$ and have to show that $\Bbb R P ^{n+1} = e^0 \cup e^1 \cup \dots \cup e^{n+1}$.

I see that $$\Bbb RP^{n+1} \cong D^{n+1} \coprod_f \Bbb R P^n \cong D^{n+1} \coprod_f ( e^0 \cup e^1 \cup \dots \cup e^n) = \bigcup_{i=0}^nD^{n+1}\coprod_f e^i$$

but from here I'm a little confused as to how to proceed.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Think of $\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}\R P^n$ as $\R^n\cup \R P^{n-1}$
where $\R P^{n-1}$ are points at infinity. Also think of the closed
cell $B^n$ as the closed Euclidean unit ball with centre the origin,
and radius $1$. Let $\phi$ be a continuous bijection from $[0,1)$
to $[0,\infty)$, for example, $\phi(x)=x/(1-x)$. Map $B^n$ to $\R P^n$
as follows: for $|v|<1$ map $v$ to $|v|^{-1}\phi(|v|)v$
(check this is OK at $v=0$) and for $|v|=1$ map $v$ to the "point
at infinity" on $\R P^{n-1}$ in the direction $\vec{0v}$. This is
then the attaching map for an $n$-cell, making $\R P^n$ into
a $e_n\cup \R P^{n-1}$.